# C program infinite unary operation not working

Tags: c, process, fork

I have three c programs double.c to double the integer, root.c to take square root of integer and square to take square of a integer

```
./root 9
output:3
./square 9
81
./double 3
ouput:6
```

I want to chain these operation like **pattern will be of left to right**

```
./square root square double 8
pattern = double(square(root(square(8))))
```

or it can be somthing like

```
./root square 8
pattern = square(root(8))
```

What i tried is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

double operate(char * operation, double operand) {
    if (strcmp(operation, "square") == 0) {
        return pow(operand, 2);
    } else if (strcmp(operation, "root") == 0) {
        return sqrt(operand);
    } else if (strcmp(operation, "double") == 0) {
        return 2 * operand;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <operand> <operation1> <operation2> ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    double operand = atof(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {
        operand = operate(argv[i], operand);
    }
    printf("Result: %.2f\n", operand);
    return 0;
}
```

**Which work something like**

```
gcc main.c -o main
./main 8 square root double
output = Works fine
```

But it is somehow different way to do it and there were some constraints before to implement this before
**Following were constraints**

• If your implementation results in parent-child relationship between
processes, then parent process must wait for its child process to exit

System calls and library functions
You must only use the below mentioned APIs to implement this question

```
- fork
 - exec* family
 - str* family
 - ato* family
 - printf, sprintf
 - round
```

**But i am unable to grasp this how it is related to process and how it will be done** Please guide me some right direction so i can do complete this.

Comment: The constraints given imply that your program must not call the `sqrt()` or `pow()` functions (though `pow()` is a terrible way to square a number anyway).  The intent seems to be that your program should use the external `root`, `square`, and `double` programs to perform the mathematical operations.  That's where `fork` and `exec` come in, and somewhat also the string, `ato*`, and `printf`-family functions as well.

Comment: `double operand = atof(argv[1]);` `for (int i = 2; i < argc; i++) {` You are working from the front. You need to from the back. The number is in `argv[argc - 1]`

Comment: But I note that although the instructions say that if you create child processes then the parents must wait for them, the list of APIs does not include any of the `wait` family of functions.  This is probably an oversight, but you should confirm with your instructor.

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for, but if you've got those three programs, the easy way to do this sort of thing is in the shell: `square $(root $(double 8))`

Comment: @JohnBollinger can you explain something like how fork and exec are applying here or there is no need to do so?

Comment: @SteveSummit ok i am trying something like this

Comment: @timpbill, if one program wants to launch another programmatically, then the `exec`* family of functions is the primary way to do so.  If the original program wants to keep running when the new one starts, then it must `fork` a child in which the `exec` is performed, for the `exec`-family functions cause the launched program to *replace* the one that launched it.  See also my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to chain these operation like pattern will be of left to right
>
> ```
> ./square root square double 8
> pattern = double(square(root(square(8))))
> ```

Presumably, such a chain can start with any of the three operations, so each of your programs needs to know how to do such chaining.  Also, as you seem to recognize, the code you present doesn't meet the requirements because it uses a separate command to run the chain.

Let's consider the constraints for a moment.  The requirement (both practical and explicit) that parent processes must wait for their children, combined with omission from the allowed list of any function that would allow parent processes to do so, implies that `fork()` is a red herring.  You must not `fork()` because you are not permitted to wait.

Also, neither `pow()` nor `sqrt()` is on your list of allowed functions.  `x * x` is a better method of squaring than `pow()` anyway, but if you want to avoid `sqrt()` then you'll need to implement a numerical method to compute square roots.  For example, you might perform a binary search for the root, or apply [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

As for the chaining, I see two main implementation approaches available:

1. **All the programs are *the same* program**, which identifies the first operation in the sequence based on the name by which it is launched (`argv[0]`).  It reads the numeric argument, then just applies each operation in turn, starting at argument 0.  It prints the result when there are no more operations to perform.

***OR***

2. **The three programs are each specific to a single operation**.  When run, they pick the numeric operand from their last argument and perform their particular operation on it.  Then,

   - if there are no other arguments (`argc == 2`), they print the result;
   - otherwise, they format the result as a string, and use, say, `execve()` (without forking) to run the tail of the chain of operations on the intermediate result.

Details are left as the exercise they are meant to be.

Comment: i understand you try to say it can be chained like this ./square root double(8) or by any other program using exec* family but can you guide me some more or can you please refer me a site where i can read this and it will be easy for me to understand and implement

Comment: @timpbill, the `exec`-family functions have documentation, probably on your machine itself, but definitely on line.  For example, https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp.  And no doubt your favorite search engine will turn up plenty of hits, including elsewhere on SO.  And this assumes that you have not already been introduced to these functions in class, which would be a bit surprising given the details of the assignment.  Finding and using documentation is an essential skill, and I do you the favor of not stealing this learning experience from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, instead:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>

double operate(char * operation, double operand) {
    if (strcmp(operation, "square") == 0) {
        return operand * operand;
    } else if (strcmp(operation, "root") == 0) {
        return sqrt(operand);
    } else if (strcmp(operation, "double") == 0) {
        return 2 * operand;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s <operand> <operation1> <operation2> ...\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    double operand = atof(argv[argc - 1]);
    for (int i = argc - 2; i > 1; i--) {
        operand = operate(argv[i], operand);
    }
    printf("Result: %.2f\n", operand);
    return 0;
}
```

Like said in the comments, you need to start from the last arguments. So you start from `argc - 2`, which will be the 2nd last.

Also, you don't seem to be allowed to use `pow`, so just do `operand * operand`, instead. `sqrt` isn't in your list either, but I would guess that's a mistake. If not, you could use some approximation.

---

The simplest way to calculate the square root without the `sqrt` function would be to use [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to find the positive root of the function

[image: f(x)=x^2-a]

```c
#define EPSILON 0.001

double simple_abs(double x)
{
    return x > 0 ? x : -x;
}

double simple_sqrt(double x)
{
    double previous = 0;
    double guess = x;

    while (simple_abs(guess - previous) > EPSILON)
    {
        previous = guess;
        guess = previous - (previous * previous - x) / (2 * previous);
    }

    return guess;
}
```

This is not the most optimal solution, but is the one I find the most simple.

Comment: I want to implement without using sqrt please can you do so

Comment: @timpbill Added a simple implementation using Newton's method

Comment: It can sometimes be a fine line to walk between helping someone and doing their homework for them (which helps no one).  This seems to me to fall on the latter side.

Comment: This is good to find sqrt of a integer